# How to open PDF/A-1 documents with a PdfCopy/PdfStamper that has a PDFA-2 or PDF/A-3 Conformance Level

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfa

I'm still trying to convert from PDF to PDF/A, from PDF/A-1 to PDF/A-2, from PDF/A-2 to PDF/A-3. As you can see, my aim is it to achieve a PDF/A-3 conformance file from an existing PDF file.

The problem by converting PDF/A-1 to PDF/A-2b is that it doesn't work. I am trying to open a PDF/A-1 conformance pdf-file with PdfACopy that shall create a PDF/A-2 conformance file, but this error occurs.

> Different PDF/A versions.

Here is a little extract from my code:

```
 using (Document doc = new Document())
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destPdfA, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
                {
                    using (PdfACopy copy = new PdfACopy(doc, fs, PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_2B))
                    {
                        copy.SetPdfVersion(PdfCopy.PDF_VERSION_1_7);
                        copy.SetTagged();
                        copy.CreateXmpMetadata();
                        doc.Open();

                        ICC_Profile icc = ICC_Profile.GetInstance(ICC);
                        copy.SetOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org", "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", icc);

                        copy.AddDocument(reader);
                        PdfStructureTreeRoot s = copy.StructureTreeRoot;
                        Boolean a = PdfStructTreeController.CheckTagged(reader);
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I create or convert those PDFs? Do I need to read the metadata from the original file, change the PDF/a version, read it again and then change it?

**Please, tell me how to convert those files. I just want a PDF-A3 conformance file.**

Comment: Which one of these lines is throwing that exception? What version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: I forgot to post the rest of my code. It's `copy.AddDocument(reader)` , which throws the error.
I am using the latest Version 5.5.8.

The error is also thrown when I'm using 
`for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                            {
                                copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i));
                            }`

Comment: @ChrisHaas The error occurs, cause he checks the "metadata". He compares the metadata PDF-Type (e.g. PDF A/2b) and I want to create a PDF A/3b conform file. So he compares the metadata of each and throws the error.
Do I have to manipulate my data so that I create a PDF A/3b document, change the metadata and then change it back to PDF A/3b.

Comment: Sorry I'm not going to be much help on this, my knowledge of PDF/A is limited and I don't have enough time to dive deep into this.

Comment: Hi @Andy, Did you ever got a solution for this?